# Tableu formula in SQL

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a tableu formula

```
if [ADMIT] = [Date] then [ADMIT] 
else ifnull([ADMIT],ifnull([Date],ifnull([EncStrDate],[Usbank_Date])))
end
```

I try to make them in sql view, add those query in my sql view.

`[Admit]` is date from table `[SMS Data file]`
`[EncStrDate]` is date from table `[Soarian Data file]`
`[Date]` is date from table `[USBank]`

Comment: Please add your table schema, we need to know how to join your tables, and add your dbms.

Answer (score 0):

Use  Sql  "Case When" sintaxis

Case when Admit = Date then Admit

```
 when Admit is not null then Admit

 when Date is not null then Date
```

when EncStraDate is not null then EncStraDate

```
else UsBankDate
```

End Case